# Vertex AI Object Tracking with only one label

Tags: google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai, object-tracking

I want to train an object tracking model in Vertex AI for one type of object. The "Train New Model" button says "To train a model, you must have at least two labels and each label included in training must have at least 15 videos assigned to it." I do not find any explanation of this requirement in the documentation. Does anyone know why I must have two labels?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum condition you have mentioned to train a model is required for Vertex AI to know what object to look for, The model will learn to identify the patterns for tracking by setting bounding boxes and label for the object. Generally by having more videos with label will produce a better outcome for the training. To see more details please visit the article [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/beginner/beginners-guide#prepare_your_data).

Also I believe having more than 1 label is needed for the model to identify an object by having a reference comparison from the 2nd label. This can be handy when you are in the part of [evaluating and testing](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/beginner/beginners-guide#evaluate_test_and_deploy_your_model) your model as you can tune your `score threshold` and `prediction outcome` for a more precise model.